# How to reset qTip2 validation?

Tags: validation, jquery-validate, qtip2

I have a form in an ASP.Net MVC project on which I am using qTip2 to display validation erros. On that form, I also have text fields that are activated/deacivated depending on choices made with radio buttons. When fields are not to be used, I set their disabled="disabled" properties. This ensures that client side validation (jQuery unobtrusive validation) for these fields is also deactivated. Now, I am wondering how to reset the qTip2 "bubbles" for fields that get disabled.

Let's say I have radio buttons 1 and 2 that enable text boxes A and B respectively. Let's also say that radio button 1 is selected by default, and that text boxes A and B are required fields when the corresponding radio button is selected. If I press on the Submit button without filling any text field,  a qTip error bubble appears beside text box A. Now, if I press on radio button 2, I have to clear that bubble, disable text box A and its validation, and enable text box B and its validation. However, if I press submit at this point without filling text box B, no error bubble appears and the form is not getting submitted.

I tried various combinations of the following commands to accomplish this, but then the validation errors get completely disabled:

```
$('.qtip').remove();
$('.qtip').hide();
$("input.input-validation-error").removeClass("input-validation-error"); // watch out for the error message labels or they won't go away
$('form').data('validator').resetForm();
$("form").validate().form();
```

No matter what combinations of these commands I execute after a radio button got clicked and the proper text-boxes disabled/enabled, the qTip bubbles disappear, but they never reappear even if I click on the Submit button and other errors should appear on the form.

I am probably not using the right commands to reset qTip validation bubbles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution right after posting the question. I used the solution proposed on this page http://johnculviner.com/?tag=/unobtrusive-validation-reset that I modified a bit. I added the following line: $form.find('input').qtip('destroy');

It gives this:

```
//Taken from: http://johnculviner.com/?tag=/unobtrusive-validation-reset
(function ($) {
    $.fn.resetValidation = function () {
        var $form = this.closest('form');

        //Destroy qTip error bubbles (http://craigsworks.com/projects/forums/thread-using-qtip-with-jquery-validation-framework)
        //$form.find('input:not(.errormessage)').qtip('destroy');
        $form.find('input').qtip('destroy');

        //reset jQuery Validate's internals
        $form.validate().resetForm();

        //reset unobtrusive validation summary, if it exists
        $form.find("[data-valmsg-summary=true]")
            .removeClass("validation-summary-errors")
            .addClass("validation-summary-valid")
            .find("ul").empty();

        //reset unobtrusive field level, if it exists
        $form.find("[data-valmsg-replace]")
            .removeClass("field-validation-error")
            .addClass("field-validation-valid")
            .empty();

        return $form;
    };

    //reset a form given a jQuery selected form or a child
    //by default validation is also reset
    $.fn.formReset = function (resetValidation) {
        var $form = this.closest('form');

        $form[0].reset();

        if (resetValidation == undefined || resetValidation) {
            $form.resetValidation();
        }

        return $form;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Then when a radio button is clicked, I call $("form").resetValidation(); after the proper fields have been enabled/disabled.